# Why does Excel 2007 pt-PT Trim all cells results in error?

Tags: excel, vba, trim

I'm using excel 2007 - pt-PT and I'm trying to trim all cells (compactar) in my worksheet using a vba script.
The following script returns this error - **"Object does not support this property or method"** and I don't understand why.

```
Sub TrimAllCells()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    cell = WorksheetFunction.Compactar(cell)
    Next cell
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `WorksheetFunction.Trim`?

Comment: VBA uses the English version of worksheet function names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Excel functions are localized, the corresponding methods in the object model library are not - having different members per localization would mean a different build version for every possible localization, and then support and debugging would be unfathomably chaotic. Not to mention, some locales use non-ANSI characters, which the VBE could have a hard time displaying correctly.

`Application.WorksheetFunction` is early-bound - that means the compiler knows what it's looking at, so when you type the dot in `WorksheetFunction.`, you get a list of all members of that object; `Compactar` (or any other localized worksheet function name) isn't in that list - hence the "object does not support this property or method" compile error.

Rule of thumb, when you're coding against an early-bound object, the list of members you get when you type the `.` derefencing operator is the list of everything you can legally do with that object. There *are* cases where sometimes members are hidden (you can make them visible in the Object Browser; F2 and right-click anywhere, select "show hidden members"), and cases where late-bound members are tacked-on at run-time on an extensible COM interface, but generally speaking, if it's not in the list of members, it's not a legal member to call.

If you used the late-bound equivalent, your code *would* compile - and blow up at run-time with error 438 instead (the late-bound / run-time equivalent of the compile-time error you're getting):

```
cell = Application.Compactar(cell) '<~ error 438 at run-time
```

You're looking for the `Trim` worksheet function... but note that VBA has its own `Trim` function, so you don't even need to get `WorksheetFunction` involved for this.

Note that you are [implicitly assigning to the default member](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ImplicitDefaultMemberAssignment) of the `Range` class here. More explicit code would be like this:

```
cell.Value = Trim(cell.Value) ' fully-qualified: VBA.Strings.Trim
```

But, this assumes there is no worksheet error - if any `cell` contains e.g. `#VALUE!` or `#REF!`, then this would raise a *type mismatch* error. Always validate the type of cell values before treating them as a `String`, as a `Date`, or any `Double` or otherwise numeric value - the `IsError` function can be used to avoid working with a `Variant/Error` value and accidentally coercing it into a `String`:

```
If Not IsError(cell.Value) Then cell.Value = Trim(cell.Value)
```

Comment: I get type mismatch now

Comment: @Eunito good, progress! Could it be that `cell.Value` contains a `Variant/Error` value? See edit.

Comment: Just a note - `WorksheetFunction.Trim` and `Trim` don't have exactly the same behavior. The `WorksheetFunction` will remove extra whitespace within a string, i.e. between words,  while `Trim` only removes leading/trailing spaces on the string as a whole. Not sure which OP wants.

Comment: @BigBen thanks, that's good to know - that makes `WorksheetFunction.Trim` wildly non-standard =)

Comment: Agreed. It is however quite useful parsing semi-unstructured text files with lots of whitespace inbetween words (don't ask, very crappy data).

Comment: I'll give it a try but I also believe I need to do a Clean first... there are many \n in there... could that also cause the error?

Comment: No, a line break shouldn't cause any errors. As far as string-handling is concerned, it's just another character.